# ClassNotFoundException with dynamically generated and compiled source code

Tags: java, file

The following code works correctly but in some cases when `Class.forName` method accesses the file it throws `ClassNotFoundException` because the file is not completely written, I solve the problem in those cases by increasing the sleep time.

But I want a way that forces the thread sleeps until file becomes completely written in stead of the static `sleep(5000)`   ?

```
public void run(String className, String code) {
    String pkgname = "pkg" + (int) (Math.random() * 10000);
    String sb = "";
    sb += "package " + pkgname + ";\n";
    sb += code;

    File javaFile = new File(serverPath + pkgname + "/" + className + ".java");
    if (javaFile.getParentFile()
            .exists() || javaFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
                try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(javaFile);
                writer.write(sb);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);// here is the problem 
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(InlineCompiler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
                int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, javaFile.getPath());
                try {
                    String[] params = new String[0];
                    Method method = Class.forName(pkgname + "." + className).getMethod("main", String[].class);
                    method.invoke(null, (Object) params);

                } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(InlineCompiler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

                }

            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException exp) {
                Logger.getLogger(InlineCompiler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exp);

            }
}}
```

**Again:** my problem is not the logic of the code or of Compiling and executing the file dynamically but it is only related to the sleeping time.

Exception when I decreased sleep to 2000

```
    Jun 27, 2015 3:06:28 AM compile.InlineCompiler run
SEVERE: null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pkg5958.test
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at compile.InlineCompiler.run(InlineCompiler.java:49)
```

Comment: What happens if you try to reopen the file (using a new file handle instead of javaFile) after calling writer.close()?

Comment: @Tabaqui nothing happens it opens it correctly

Comment: Can you please post the full exception and stack trace when you get the exception?  Thank you.  Right now, I'm having a hard time understanding how the sleeping helps at all.

Comment: Is there any output from the compiler?  You have configured it to send output to stdout and stderr.

Comment: this has nothing to do with `Thread.sleep()` I have no idea why you even put that in there or why you think it should be part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Writing the file is not the problem:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pkg5958.test` means that some a class named `test` in a package named `pkg5989` that the runtime is trying to reference is not on the classpath. This has nothing to do with `Thread.sleep()`.

#### The directory you are generating the `.class` file into is **not** on your classpath.

> I could not reproduce your problem, did not think I could.
>   This works and there is not a single call to `Thread.sleep()`!

#### [Q31083880.java](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q31083880.java)

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Q31083880
{
    public static int compile(@Nonnull final File file)
    {
        final JavaCompiler c = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        return c.run(null, null, null, file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    public static void invoke(@Nonnull final String name)
    {
        try
        {
            final URLClassLoader cl = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            final Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            final File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
            method.invoke(cl, f.toURI().toURL());
            final Method m;
            try
            {
                m = Class.forName(name).getMethod("main", String[].class);
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            final String[] args = new String[0];
            m.invoke(null, new Object[]{args});
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException | MalformedURLException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Test.java");
        try
        {
            final FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
            try
            {
                final String source = "public class Test { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println(\"Testing\"); } }";
                fw.write(source);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                try { fw.close(); } catch (final IOException e) { System.err.println(e.getMessage()); }
            }
            System.out.println(compile(f));
            invoke("Test");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles to `System.getProperty("user.home");` as an example.

It is an exercise to the reader to change this behavior, which should be easy.

Comment: Have you run Jarrod's code?

Comment: Your answer guided me to the answer of my problem,Thanks :)